# RestTemplate uriVariables not expanded

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I try to access a rest endpoint by using springs RestTemplate.getForObject() but my uri variables are not expanded, and attached as parameters to the url. This is what I got so far:

```
Map<String, String> uriParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
uriParams.put("method", "login");
uriParams.put("input_type", DATA_TYPE);
uriParams.put("response_type", DATA_TYPE);
uriParams.put("rest_data", rest_data.toString());
String responseString = template.getForObject(endpointUrl, String.class, uriParams);
```

the value of the endpointUrl Variable is `http://127.0.0.1/service/v4_1/rest.php` and it's exactely what it's called but I'd expect `http://127.0.0.1/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type...` to be called.
Any hints are appreciated.

I'm using Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE

Regards.

Comment: Please post the value of your endpointUrl

Comment: You can follow bellow link. It has full working code with description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815850/3073945

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is no append some query string logic in [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) it basically replace variable like `{foo}` by their value:

```
http://www.sample.com?foo={foo}
```

becomes:

```
http://www.sample.com?foo=2
```

if `foo` is 2.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but according to the documentation, the option with the uriParams-map should work as well.

Comment: it works but you need to have variable in your url (it's a map of variables)

Comment: A tiny bit larger answer here would be helpful; when I first read your answer it didn't really click. Take time to show actual snippet of code where you represent the URL as a String and then the value in a map and then calling getForObject(string, map). I up-voted this but it should be made more explicit IMO.

Comment: You'd think this would be up-front in the Javadocs...but I had to come here, to a 5-year-old answer, to find it out.

Answer (score 45):

The currently-marked answer from `user180100` is technically correct but not very explicit. Here is a more explicit answer, to help those coming along behind me, because the answer didn't quite make sense to me at first.

```
String url = "http://www.sample.com?foo={fooValue}";

Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put("fooValue", "2");

// "http://www.sample.com?foo=2"
restTemplate.getForObject(url, Object.class, uriVariables);
```

Comment: Note that `RestTemplate` also has a method signature that takes varargs, so you can also do this: `int foo = 2; restTemplate.getForObject("http://www.sample.com?foo={foo}", Object.class, foo);`

Comment: when using restTemplate, this is the correct answer.