# Issue with uriVariable in RestTemplate.exchange method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring-web version 5.0.6.RELEASE.

I tried calling the GET exchange method with the URI variable map, but these URI variables are not set to the final URL which hit the external system.

My code snippet is as below

```
Map<String,Object> queryParam =  new HashMap<>();
queryParam.put("id", 1);
queryParam.put("name", "ABC");
ResponseEntity<List<MyResponse>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(serverUrl.toString(),HttpMethod.GET,null,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyResponse>>(){}, queryParam);
```

When I debugged , I found `RestTemplate.execute` method have a URI creation code 
`URI expanded = getUriTemplateHandler().expand(url, uriVariables);` which does not set the URI params to `URI` class.

I furthur debugged and found that in `DefaultUriBuilderFactory.build()`method the URI variable is not passed or set to URI component builder

`UriComponents uriComponents = this.uriComponentsBuilder.build().expand(uriVars);` which causes 
`HierarchicalUriComponents expandInternal(UriTemplateVariables uriVariables)` method of `HierarchicalUriComponents` class to set the URI variable as empty.

Can anyone help me understand if I am doing anything wrong here or Spring web have any bug for such cases?

Comment: You haven't shared the most important bits. What does `serverUrl.toString()` looks like? The expand of URI variables require variables to be set in the url in the first place. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705377/resttemplate-urivariables-not-expanded answers your question?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I got the answer , so here to use the queryParam MAP , we have to set the variable name in URL string like `http://localhost:8080/service?id={id}&name={name}` , however I think this should be designed in a different way  or  may be we can have better documentation with example as we can see lot many developer are confused with its usage. Thanks